# Conditionally insert Child using knitr

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, sweave

I'm trying to insert children into main.Rnw, as seen here:

```
<<child = here("child.Rnw") >>=
@
```

The Problem is, that `child.Rnw` isn't always needed. So I want to check if the file exists - if it does, it should be inserted, otherwise do nothing.

I tried the following:

```
# 1
\IfFileExists{./child.Rnw}{
    \Sexpr{knit_child(here("child.Rnw"))}
}{}

# 2 Try 
\iftrue\Sexpr{file.exists(here("Demofiles","Demopart.Rnw"))}{
    \Sexpr{knit_child(here("Demofiles","Demopart.Rnw"))}
}{}
```

Both works, if the file exists, but deleting it gives the following error while compiling the PDF:

```
Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2))
```

The output reveals the following:

```
'child.Rnw' No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to conditionally input a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
\Sexpr{if(file.exists("child.Rnw")) knit_child("child.Rnw")}
```

?